# iOS Keyboard Extension - prohibit showing custom keyboard in Keyboard list until user purchase

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I have made `Custom Keyboard Extension` in one of my app. And this is working fine too with all the devices perfectly.

Extension is `automatically installed in the OS`. Right? - Yes

PROBLEM :

I want to prohibit users to select MY KEYBOARD from `"Add New Keyboard..."` list `UNTIL USER BUY IT`.

Whenever user make `In-App Purchase successfully`. `I want to add custom keyboard to the "Add New Keyboard..." list`. and then users are free to use it.

So is it possible. ??? Any advices are appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What about just let the users install the keyboard, but don't let them use it while they didn't bought it. Like add a view over the keyboard that said they need to buy the keyboard? Maybe if it's possible let them use some features of your keyboard, and they need to buy to unlock all.

Comment: Forget my comment, it's not allowed https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#extensions